# How to block the popups alert on beforeUnload while using custom alert popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, alert, confirm

I am using `JqueryUI` for custom `Confirm box` when user clicks on a button.

Here is the script,

```
    function exit() {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Restore": function () {
                        callClick();
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Here is the HTML code

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Exit" OnClientClick="exit()" />
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Proceed Confirmation?">
        <p>Are you sure you want to exit?</p>
    </div
```

When user click on proceed button i want to call another function.

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
        function callClick() {
            $('#test').click()
        }
```

But as soon as button is clicked alert popups appear along with my custom made alert popup.

i wish to disable the default popup.

please see below image for referrence.
[image]

Comment: You're using an ASP.Net button which has `runat="server"` set on it, as such it's going to unload the page before any JS runs.

Comment: what can be the alternate option?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method `window.onbeforeunload = function(event){}` to catch this event.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.Please check the question i have updated

Comment: @Shahid, try to put it window.onbeforeunload = null; above of callClick function